# How can i get my codes work exactly like i have it in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good Day all, i have been working with http://jsfiddle.net, the sample app i built and tested on jsfiddle is working fine and working as i want it. Now i have tried copy my codes out and run it on my local machine but its seems not working but the same exact codes are working online(jsfiddle).Here is the working version http://jsfiddle.net. Below is the structure of my codes locally which is not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="key, words" />
<meta name="description" content="description" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="alternate" title="Website Feed" href="rss.php" type="application/rss+xml" />
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<title>AstroSD</title>
<script>
var MyCheckboxes=$("input[name='toggle']");

MyCheckboxes.change(function() {
$("#kickoff").toggle(MyCheckboxes.is(":checked"));
$("#goal").toggle(MyCheckboxes.is(":checked"));
$("#halfull").toggle(MyCheckboxes.is(":checked"));
$("#halftime/fulltime").toggle(MyCheckboxes.is(":checked"));   
});

$(function(){
$("#slideThree").change(function() {
$('#move').toggleClass("show-hide", this.checked)
$('#back').toggleClass("show-hide", this.checked)
$('#goal').toggleClass("show-hide", this.checked)
$('#halfull').toggleClass("show-hide", this.checked)
}).change();
})
</script></head>
```

I need help in structuring the head part using the script i have in http://jsfiddle.net/ so it will work accordingly. i believe am missing something here. thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you included jQuery in your head?

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the bottom right frame and viewing the source/saving it?

Comment: no error, its not just working, meaning that i copied the same codes have in jsfiddle in to my normal editor, i took the html part of the codes i have in jsfiddle and save it as index.html, at the header part of the index.html, i have the codes above. but still not. working.

Comment: Your code above doesn't have jQuery included in the head. Do what Tats_innit said below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference in the src code of jsfiddle and your code above is this:

Hope you have given the Jquery src correctly: (Also if I may suggest - please use latest JQ library i.e. 1.7.. version but you know your code better)

Add this to your page please, hope it fits the need. `:)`

*script*

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Tats_innit, LeeR, Bill and  arxanas. Its working Fine.

Comment: @ApuloOhaleCosmasLite lol yay `:)` we all have been there, Glad it helped, I will +1 you anyways,